# What is the probability of winning this Jackpot Lottery?

Tags: probability, self-study, geometric-distribution

I am working on some more exam practice questions, and just want to see if I am approaching this question correctly?

Here is the complete question:

2,250 numbers are drawn at random without replacement from a barrel containing
150,000 ticket numbers.

After all the 2250 numbers are drawn, they are returned to the barrel and a
second number (a jackpot number) is drawn at random.

If this jackpot number is the same as one of the 2,250 previously drawn numbers, a jackpot prize is awarded. If the jackpot prize is NOT won (that is, the prize winning number is different from one of the 2,250 jackpot numbers), then the number is returned to the barrel and another number is drawn at random.

The selection process is repeated until the jackpot prize is won.

(1) Find the probability that the jackpot prize is won at any draw.

(2) The jackpot prize is initially 10,000, and it increases by 10,000 each time the jackpot
prize is NOT won. Find is the probability that the jackpot prize will exceed 250,000 when the jackpot is finally won.

(3) Let X be a random variable representing the number of draws until the jackpot prize is
finally won. What is P(X = k)? What is the corresponding total prize money won?

(4) What is the expected winning of this Jackpot Lottery?

Here is my train of thought:

(1) This one seemed like a bit of a trick question - since it explicitly states that the selection process is repeated until the jackpot is won - so the probability should be 1.

Otherwise, I believe that this can be modeled by a geometric discrete distribution? So the probability of the jackpot prize being won at $x$, should be:

$P(X=x)=(1- \frac{2,250}{150,000})^{x-1}(\frac{2,250}{150,000})$

(2) The first "success" in which the prize money exceeds 250,000 would be on the 26th try and thereafter the prize money exceeds this amount, so the probability of the jackpot prize exceeding 250K is:

$1-P(X \le 25)$, which works out to be $0.0298$

(3) I have this answer as essentially the same as (1) (Actually what is the difference?)

$P(X=k)=(1- \frac{2,250}{150,000})^{k-1}(\frac{2,250}{150,000})$ and the prize money would be $10,000 \cdot k$

(4) For this question, I derive the expected value for a geometric distribution to be:

$U_{x} = \frac{1}{p}$ and since $p = \frac{2,250}{150,000}$ the expected draw is $\frac{150,000}{2,250}$ = 66.67. So the expected winning is $10,000\cdot67$ (rounding up)

I would greatly appreciate any feedback for the way I have answered the questions - have I approached it correctly? In particular, what would be the difference between Q1 and Q3, and is my answer to Q4 correct?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer to (1) is just $\tfrac{2250}{150000}$, since it's asking the probability of a win on a single draw. Other than that, what you've said appears to be correct.

Comment: Actually, I think my calculation for (2) is drastically off? I'm doing it again and I get 0.68 - do you get the same?